# I want to show record in two different columns by category

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have one column `voucher_category` in my table in this I have two `(ENUM)`types of data `cash_receipt` and `cash_payment`.
 And also I have One more  `Voucher_type` column in my table in this I have two type `credit` and `debit`.
I want to show `voucher_category` by `Voucher_type` in two different column like following table

```
 I want this type of columns

 Voucher No  Voucher_Category_By_Credit  Voucher_Category_By_Debit         
         1               cash payment 
         2                                         cash receipt


Currently I'am receiving like this bellow

 Voucher No      Voucher_Category           voucher_category_type         
       1            cash payment               credit
       2            cash receipt                debit
```

This is my code

```
Controller



$modResult  = $this->sendValues->receiving($data);

<tr>
  <th>Voucher No.</th>
  <th>Voucher_Category</th>
  <th>voucher_category_type</th>
</tr>

      <?php foreach($modResult as $voucher):?>
       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_no'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_category'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_category_type'];?></td>
        </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>


model


public function receiving($data){
        extract($data);

            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('ts_voucher');

          $this->db->where('voucher_category','cash_receipt');
          $this->db->or_where('voucher_category','cash_payment');

           $query=$this->db->get();
           return $query->result_array();

 }
```

Comment: Could always use a pivot, but I would imagine that gets messy when you're using php.

Comment: And what is the problem with the given code? What is not working yet? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This changes should work, depending on your code example:

```
<tr>
  <th>Voucher No</th>
  <th>Voucher_Category_By_Credit</th>
  <th>Voucher_Category_By_Debit</th>
</tr>

      <?php foreach($modResult as $voucher):?>
       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_no'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_category_type']=='credit' ? $voucher['voucher_category'] : '';?></td>
         <td><?php echo $voucher['voucher_category_type']=='debit' ? $voucher['voucher_category'] : '';?></td>
        </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
```